# Convert this MySQL to Sybase

Tags: mysql, sql, sap-ase

I have the following MySQL:

```
SET @sql = NULL;
SELECT
  GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT
    CONCAT(
      'sum(case when perm = ''',
      perm,
      ''' then 1 else 0 end) AS ',
      perm
    )
  ) INTO @sql
FROM perms;

SET @sql = CONCAT('SELECT role, ', @sql, ' 
                  FROM perms 
                   GROUP BY role');

PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

However, I have to use Sybase 12, does anyone know how to convert this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
declare cur_perm cursor for 
select perm from perms
go
declare @sql  varchar(4000) 
declare @perm varchar(4000) 

set @sql = ' '


open cur_perm
fetch cur_perm into @perm
while @@sqlstatus=0 begin
  select @sql = @sql+'sum(case when perm = '''+@perm+''' then 1 else 0 end) AS '''+@perm+''', '
  fetch cur_perm into @perm
end
close cur_perm
deallocate cursor cur_perm

select @sql = 'SELECT '+ @sql+' role 
                  FROM perms 
                   GROUP BY role'

exec(@sql)
```

Comment: That doesn't work as it would only gets the last perm rather than all of them.

Comment: Nope doesn't even execute....remember that I am trying to concatenate a series of `perm` from the `perms` table so I will need to do something like this anyways: `@sql = @sql + ', SUM(CASE WHEN perm = ''' + perm + ''' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS ' + perm`

Comment: Something like: `SELECT role, sum(case when perm='p1' then 1 else 0 end) AS 'p1', sum(case when perm='p2' then 1 else 0 end) AS 'p2', sum(case when perm='p3' then 1 else 0 end) AS 'p3' FROM perms GROUP BY role`

Comment: This worked but the string is longer than 255 chars and i am running Sybase 12 which means there aren't any longer data types...oh well...thanks for your help though!

Comment: Probably worth mentioning that the `set` statement didn't work in Sybase 12 but it wasn't needed....also needed to put a `go` statement after the declaration of the cursor.

Comment: Sadly, Sybase 12 only supports 1-255 size for varchar!

Comment: @Ben Do you use sybase 12 or 12.5?

Comment: 12 I believe. What in 12.5 would help?

Comment: I'm working in 12.5 and `declare @sql varchar(4000)` It's working correctly. But I'm not sure ha it works on 12.